# Setgid strange behavior

Tags: linux, permissions, setgid

I have following files:

```
----rw---- 1 wojtek users    4 Oct 26 15:56 data.txt
-rwx--s--x 1 wojtek users 8864 Oct 26 16:00 fopen_setgid
```

When I run `fopen_setgid`

- as `daro` then everything works as expected: The program runs with the `users` group permission (instead of the `daro` group) so there is no error
- as `wojtek` then I receive the error `Permission denied` but I don't know why. Shouldn't it run the program with the `users` group permission instead of the  `wojtek` group allowing the program to to successfully open the file like in the `daro` case?

The only thing that `fopen_setgid` does is to open `data.txt`

- The user `daro` is only in 1 group: `daro`
- The user `wojtek` is only 1 group: `wojtek`
- The group `users` has no members

My OS is Debian 9 (stretch)

Comment: what's `fopen_setgid`? What is it supposed to do? The only hit for it on google is this question...

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a reference, but I just tested it. The issue is not related to `setgid` but depends only on the UID, GID of the process and the file and the file permissions.

I created a file

```
echo test > test.txt
```

changed the permissions

```
chmod 064 test.txt
```

and can no longer access it

```
$ cat test.txt
cat: test.txt: Permission denied
```

although my group has `rw` access.

```
$ ls -l test.txt
----rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 5 Nov  5 16:11 test.txt
$ id
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),129(sambashare)
```

Then I changed the file owner to `root` and can successfully open the file.

```
$ sudo chown root test.txt 
$ ls -l test.txt
----rw-r-- 1 root myuser 5 Nov  5 16:11 test.txt
$ cat test.txt            
test
```

Apparently the owner access bits take precedence over the group access bits if both user and group match. (tested on Ubuntu 19.04)

So the workaround is to add `u+rw` permissions for the file or change the file owner to something else, not `wojtek` or `daro`.

Comment: So when wojtek is the owner and logged user is wojtek the system only look for a owner bits never looking for a group field when checking for a access rights?

Comment: @Spectre911 This is what I observed in my test. Unfortunately I did not (yet) find a documentation of this behavior.